Timestamp comparison and conversion to application server timezone issue with CloudSQL DB
Since cloudsql by default stores timestamp values in UTC format, how can we make the conversion of the timestamp between the application layer and DB.
The application server is MST time zone based and when am creating the sql query ( its a spring boot JPA query) I need to pass java.sql.Timestamp object for from and to Timestamp  values
The table has data for 27th day but from the UI if one passes the timestamp range as 2024-06-27 00:00:00  to 2024-06-27 23:59:59 , am getting values returned for 26th as well in the response.
I tried creating the timestamp object with
ZoneId.of("UTC+07") in the object however while parsing the returned result set
the timestamp column ( created_at  ) is printing the value with previous day timestamp  for the resultset row
How can i ensure that what the user enters, the query while converting to UTC maintains the same time frame for querying and also while parsing the result
Ex: Input in UI/app (MST)  - 2024-06-27 00:00:00  to 2024-06-27 23:59:59
while querying to DB it queries for same timeframe in UTC and while returning the resultset and parsing the timestamp column value gives timestamp in same day.

Move away from the '3 letter timezones'. They are at best ambiguous and at worst misleading/incorrect. Do you mean America/Phoenix?

yeah America/Phoenix

If you're using Hibernate then the most accurate and reusable you can get (because of what the answer below so clearly states about the lack of proper support in RDBMSs for ZonedDateTime) is to use Instant and store the user's timezone separately.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


I need to pass java.sql.Timestamp object

I doubt that. But, if it's true, what you want is impossible - Timestamp objects just contain millis (and nanos) since the epoch, timezone info is lost.
java.util.Date, and all the sql types that extend it (java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp) are quite broken and should not be used.
JDBC, which is the low level glue that makes java <-> SQL db interaction work, allows you to pass the corrected types, which are java.time.Instant, java.time.OffsetDateTime, and java.time.LocalDateTime. Unfortunately, the 'best' type for this stuff, java.time.ZonedDateTime, isn't required to work as per the JDBC spec (so, JDBC drivers are free to allow it, but don't have to) and usually does not work, which is the fault of DBs, not java (DBs like storing timezones as offsets which isn't how you store those, but java can't change how DBs work).
There is no .setLocalDateTime / .setInstant / .setOffsetDateTime method in PreparedStatement, but .setObject(someInstanceOfLocalDateTime) does work. There is no ResultSet.getLocalDateTime() method the way there is .getTimestamp() method, but ResultSet.getObject(colIdx, LocalDateTime.class) works, and, the JDBC spec in fact says it has to work or the JDBC driver isn't compliant.
I don't know if you're writing direct JDBC queries or using some abstraction layer (hibernate, JDBI, JOOQ, or similar). But, either those methods are called 'under the hood' or what you want is not possible without resorting to fragile hacks. Fix you code if you can, and if you are using an abstraction layer that demands you pass java.sql.Timestamp, get rid of that layer and find another one to use. Which might be a lot of work, but, that'd be how to fix this problem.

Am using Hibernate  - JPA                                                                                              When i tried executing the query in the DB editor select * from table where created_at >= '2024-06-27 00:00:00+07' and created_at <= '2024-06-27 23:59:59+07' the query returned data but when  i tried to pass the same the timestamp as string it threw cast exceptions.  So i had to pass the timestamp objects..

You're not getting it. When you write: "I tried to pass the same as timestamp" that is not possible. The concept 2024-06-27 23:59:59+07 cannot be represented by java.sql.Timestamp. You need to pass OffsetDateTime objects. Those can represent that.
